# How to preserve zip file history in Git after a renaming and modifying?

Tags: git, git-lfs

When I rename a zip file and modifies it I lose the file history. Since Git 
recognize it as a new file .I tried git log command with --follow and git GUI
tools like TortoiseGit or git extension options to view a file history.
I am using Git-lfs to track all *.zip files and I also tried using textconv 
for the diff of zip files in hope it will help.
       my configuration for the textconv

```
   .gitattributes:  
          *.zip filter=lfs diff=zip merge=lfs -text

    .gitconfig file :  
        [diff "zip"]           
            textconv = unzip -c -a  
            binary = true
```

How to preserve "result.zip"  history in Git after a commit that contained 
renaming it to "result_Two.zip" and modifying it ?

Answer (score 1):

Make one commit that merely renames the zip file:

```
git mv foo.zip bar.zip
git commit -s 'rename zip file without any other changes'
```

Then, make a commit that completely replaces the contents:

```
<create new bar.zip>
git add bar.zip
git commit -s 'replace bar.zip contents'
```

Afterward, running:

```
git log --follow bar.zip
```

will show, in Git's usual backwards fashion, the "replace contents" commit, then the "rename" commit, then whatever commits affect `foo.zip` (the old name).

Answer (score 0):

It is **not possible to keep the history if a file is renamed**.

> Renames are handled implicitly rather than explicitly. A common
>   complaint with CVS is that it uses the name of a file to identify its
>   revision history, so moving or renaming a file is not possible without
>   either interrupting its history, or renaming the history and thereby
>   making the history inaccurate. Most post-CVS revision control systems
>   solve this by giving a file a unique long-lived name (a sort of inode
>   number) that survives renaming. Git does not record such an
>   identifier, and this is claimed as an advantage.

What confirms that there is no native method to change the name of a file without losing its history, Git does not have this ability.

A **solution** to maintain the history and to lookup the full history,is with the following command:

```
git log --follow ./path/to/file
```

Comment: The problem is that "git log --follow .." doesn't always works and find the file before the rename.